# How to print Java Array?

Tags: java, arrays

Sorry to bother you all but I'm new two programming and I'm really stuck on this task. I have to add code to the class to print numbers from this `array` in order to make a `for-loop`.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class ArrayExercise
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String[] numbers = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
    String numbers = number[i];
    String nextnumber = number[i + 1];
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you read Oracle's tutorial on [for loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)?

Comment: var numbers is String[] or String !?  String[] numbers = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
String numbers = number[i];

Answer (score 2):

A for loop is used as follows:

```
for( *variable used as an index*; *condition*; *index variable change*){
*loop body*
}
```

In your case, I would do something along the lines of:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}
```

(Note that i < 5 because array value positions start a 0 and go to [Array Size]-1)

The strings `numbers` and `nextnumber` in your code is unnecessary.

So your program should look like this:

```
public class ArrayExercise
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String[] numbers = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Rather than using a magic number in the loop condition (`5`), you should use `< numbers.length`

Comment: arrays are *never* variable length; they're fixed size. And they are defined elsewhere in the code and could be changed later ... which is *why* you avoid magic numbers in conditionals like that. Otherwise you'd have to remember to update the loop as well when changing the array.

Comment: So if OP or somebody else adds a new item in the array e.g. `"six"`, save the file, recompiles it and runs, the application should only print from `"one"` to `"five"`?

Answer (score 2):

One option is you can do it like this

```
public class ArrayExercise
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] numbers = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(numbers[i])
        }
    }
}
```

or, you can do it like this.

```
public class ArrayExercise
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] numbers = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
        for (String number:numbers)
        {
            System.out.println(number)
        }
    }
}
```